# what will rs.getString(1) return if the SQL query returns nothing

Tags: java, sql

heres my code :

code for connecting database :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=city_mart;user=sa;password=aptech");
Statement st=con.createStatement();

String sql="Select Emp_login_ID from employee where Emp_login_ID = '"+r3.getText()+"' ";
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);

String login = rs.getString(1);

if (r3.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(login))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Login ID not available.");
}
else
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Login ID is available.");
}
```

thanks.any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The Class.forName() line has been unnecessary since about 2007.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to call `ResultSet#next()` before calling `ResultSet#getString()`

First move the cursor at the the first row then get value of any column.

I suggest you to use `PreparedStatment` instead of `Statement`.

Read tutorial on [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and [When we use PreparedStatement instead of Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099425/when-we-use-preparedstatement-instead-of-statement)

It should be like this: (*check the value returned by rs.next()*)

```
String sql="Select Emp_login_ID from employee where Emp_login_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(sql);
st.setString(1,r3.getText());

ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
if(rs.next()){
     String login = rs.getString(1);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Login ID is available.");
}else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Login ID not available.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=city_mart;user=sa;password=aptech");
Statement st=con.createStatement();

String sql="Select Emp_login_ID from employee where Emp_login_ID = '"+r3.getText()+"' ";
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);


while(rs.next()){
  String login = rs.getString(1);
  if (r3.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(login))
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Login ID not available.");
   }
   else
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Login ID is available.");
   }
}
```

> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A
>   ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

You can read about Next method of Result Set [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())

Comment: Not a good way to use single quotes in query. It's not supported by all databases.

Comment: read [When we use PreparedStatement instead of Statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099425/when-we-use-preparedstatement-instead-of-statement)

Answer (score 0):

It will throw an exception because you have failed to call `ResultSet.next()`. If you had called it, it would have returned `false`, and you shouldn't have called `rs.getString()` at all.