# choose table according to input in jsp

Tags: java, html, mysql, jdbc

I have two tables in mysql database, one for student and one for teacher. Both tables have the same columns.

The code below inserts data only to the teacher's table. If user selects teacher's radio button, then the sign up data should be stored in teacher's table. If the user selects student's radio, then the sign up data should be stored in student's table. What will be a solution for that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rrIc.jpg)

**index.jsp**

```
<form  method="GET " action="statement2.jsp" autocomplete="on"> 
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Teacher" checked/> Teacher
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Student"/>Student
  <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
  <input type="button" onclick="location.href='reg.jsp';" value="Sign Up" />
</form>
```

---

**statement2.jsp**

```
<%
   String name=request.getParameter("first");
   String abc=request.getParameter("last");
   String cde=request.getParameter("user");
   String pass=request.getParameter("password");
   String confpass=request.getParameter("confirmpass");
   String emails=request.getParameter("email");
   String months=request.getParameter("month");
   String day=request.getParameter("day");
   String year=request.getParameter("year");
   String gender=request.getParameter("gender");

   String Sql="insert into teacher2(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender) values('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"','"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"')";
   st.executeUpdate(Sql);
%>
```

**After Correction**
**statement2.jsp**

```
<%
   String name=request.getParameter("first");
   String abc=request.getParameter("last");
   String cde=request.getParameter("user");
   String pass=request.getParameter("password");
   String confpass=request.getParameter("confirmpass");
   String emails=request.getParameter("email");
   String months=request.getParameter("month");
   String day=request.getParameter("day");
   String year=request.getParameter("year");
   String gender=request.getParameter("gender");

   if (gender != null) {
   String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";
   // replace dots with your values
   String query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"','"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"')";

   st.executeUpdate(query); 
  %>
```

---

What wrong in this query.Why this query insert data in a only a table of student

**index.jsp**

```
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="teacher" checked/> Teacher
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Student"/>Student
```

**statement2.jsp**

```
   String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
   if (gender != null) {
   String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";
// replace dots with your values
   String query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(firstname,lastname,username,password,confirmpassword,email,month,day,year,gender) VALUES ('"+name+"','"+abc+"','"+cde+"','"+pass+"','"+confpass+"','"+emails+"','"+months+"','"+day+"','"+year+"','"+gender+"')";
  st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: This code has inserted data in only one table teacher i want to insert data in student if user select radio button of student what will be code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Just choose an appropriate table and then pass it to your query statement with

```
<%
  String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
  if (gender != null) {
    String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacherTable" : "studentTable";
    // replace dots with your values
    String query = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(...) VALUES (...)";
    st.executeUpdate(query); 
  }
%>
```

Note that it's not a best choice to redirect to another jsp and use scriplets there (which are discouraged by specification) to process submitted data. I would rather recommend you to submit form to a Servlet and write all Java code there.

Also you may want to take a look at `PreparedStatement` in preference to `Statement`.

Check these answers if you are interested

[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

[When should we use a PreparedStatement instead of a Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099425/when-should-we-use-a-preparedstatement-instead-of-a-statement)

Comment: It tells you that you have syntax error with brackets. Check that all opening and closing brackets are at place.

Comment: data don't insert in teacher table when radio button is on teacher but have insert in student table when radio button is on student

Comment: `teacher` in `gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";` should match `Teacher` in `<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Teacher" checked/>`, so replace `Teacher` with `teacher`.

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="gender" value="teacher" checked/> Teacher`  but still have a problem

Comment: i think problem is here `String table = gender.equals("teacher") ? "teacher2" : "student";`

Comment: If `gender.equals("teacher")` is always `false`, then try to check its value with `<%=request.getParameter("gender") %>` and find the root cause

Comment: You mean use `<%=request.getParameter("gender") %>` instead of this `String gender = request.getParameter("gender");`

Comment: how you deals radio button as a value?