# Android Java Query String Dynamic Values after Declare Variable

Tags: java, android, string, declare

How concatenate in (?) String of a Query? Or %s like php... I know make with + but is not the case!
I need Query Change the String Value like PHP using ? or %s (similar in Android Java)...

```
package yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.actions;

import android.content.Context;

import yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.models.CategoriesModel;

public class CategoriesActions extends CategoriesModel {
    protected String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO categories (title) VALUES (?) ";
    protected String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE categories SET title=? WHERE id=?";
    protected String sqlDelete = "UPDATE FROM categories WHERE id=?";
    protected String sqlSelect = "SELECT %s FROM categories %s %s %s"; // ? or %s

    public CategoriesActions(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public boolean insert()
    {
        String cat_title = this.getTitle();
        String sql = sqlInsert; // <---------- need concatenate cat_title in sqlInser (?)

        //return sql;
        return this.RunQuery(sql);
    }

    public String update()
    {
        String sql = "";
        return sql;
    }

    public String delete()
    {
        String sql = "";
        return sql;
    }

    public String select(String columns, String where, String order, String limit)
    {
        String sql = "";
        return sql;
    }
}
```

dbConnection Layer for all Models in Project (All Models in Project extends this Class (Generic))

```
package yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class dbConnection extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private SQLiteDatabase conn;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="App.Xitano";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_CATEGORIES = "categories";
    private static final String TABLE_PAYMENT_TYPES = "payment_types";
    private static final String TABLE_TRANSACTIONS = "transactions";

    private static final String CATEGORIES_KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String CATEGORIES_KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String CATEGORIES_KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static final String CATEGORIES_KEY_UPDATED_AT = "updated_at";

    private static final String PAYMENT_TYPES_KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String PAYMENT_TYPES_KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String PAYMENT_TYPES_KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static final String PAYMENT_TYPES_KEY_UPDATED_AT = "updated_at";

    private static final String TRANSACTIONS_KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String TRANSACTIONS_KEY_IN_OUT = "in_out";
    private static final String TRANSACTIONS_KEY_CATEGORIES_ID = "categories_id";
    private static final String TRANSACTIONS_KEY_PAYMENT_TYPES_ID = "payment_types_id";
    private static final String TRANSACTIONS_KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TRANSACTIONS_KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
    private static final String CTRANSACTIONS_KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static final String TRANSACTIONS_KEY_UPDATED_AT = "updated_at";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CATEGORIES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PAYMENT_TYPES + "("
            + PAYMENT_TYPES_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + PAYMENT_TYPES_KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + PAYMENT_TYPES_KEY_CREATED_AT + "TIMESTAMP,"
            + PAYMENT_TYPES_KEY_UPDATED_AT + "TIMESTAMP );";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PAYMENT_TYPES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CATEGORIES + "("
            + CATEGORIES_KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + CATEGORIES_KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + CATEGORIES_KEY_CREATED_AT + "TIMESTAMP,"
            + CATEGORIES_KEY_UPDATED_AT + "TIMESTAMP );";

    public dbConnection(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.d("table", TABLE_CATEGORIES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        /*
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_STUDENTS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER_HOBBY);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER_CITY);
        */
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        /*
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_USER + "'");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_USER_HOBBY + "'");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '" + TABLE_USER_CITY + "'");
        onCreate(db);
        */
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase ConnectWritable(){
        this.conn = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return this.conn;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase ConnectReadable(){
        this.conn = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return this.conn;
    }

    public boolean RunQuery(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase stm = this.ConnectWritable();
        stm.execSQL(sql);
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor RunSelect(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase stm = this.ConnectReadable();
        Cursor cursor = stm.rawQuery(sql, null);
        return cursor;
    }

    public int RunCount(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase stm = this.ConnectReadable();
        Cursor cursor = stm.rawQuery(sql, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0 && cursor.getColumnCount() > 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return cursor.getInt(0);
        } else {
            cursor.close();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect(){
        this.conn.close();
        this.conn = null;
    }
}
```

Model Layer (extends dbConnection Class (Generic)

```
package yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.models;

import android.content.Context;

import yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.database.dbConnection;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class CategoriesModel extends dbConnection implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String title;

    public CategoriesModel(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

thank you!

Comment: Suggest you google prepared statements in Java!

Comment: i not belive prepared statement is good or work in this layer!

Comment: i update and insert the layers in this post... 
Anyone have any ideas for making this work in layers? ty

Comment: I need the same "bindString" of prepared statement but in String variable, not in db Object, is possible? to send the sql query ready for RunQuery function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
protected String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO categories (title) VALUES (%s) ";
public boolean insert()
{
    String sql = String.format(sqlInsert, this.getTitle());
    return this.RunQuery(sql);
}
```

Thank You, Friends!

Comment: I suggest you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099425/when-should-we-use-a-preparedstatement-instead-of-a-statement]

Answer (score 0):

You mention that prepared statements are "not good in this layer" but challenge why prepared statements would not work for you?  For example in your code you have:

```
protected String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO categories (title) VALUES (?) ";
```

you can easily create a prepared statement :

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlInsert);
```

Then all you have to do is pass the relevant parameters to the query using the set() methods available for prepared statements.  More information available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: yes. i make it.. but i need the good pratices in my layers! in my layers i need prepareStatement variable and it is possible only in the dbConnection layer!

Comment: i need know how i prepareStatement (similar) in actions layer... a similar functions for bind the variable sql... i make it in dbConnection in another code, but it is a bad practices...