# You have an error in your SQL syntax check the manual JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm getting this error while trying to run this code 
You have an error in 
your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near ''And StatusMembership=Active' at line 1

```
public boolean checkLenderToIfExists(BorrowedBook borrowedBook) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM library_students.student WHERE StudentID='"+ borrowedBook.getLenderTo()+"'And Permission=1"+"'And StatusMembership='Active'");
        if (!(rs.next())) {
            return false;
        }
        rs.close();
        return true;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: 'And I think you'll need to remove that first ' there. Or you need one before the 1

Comment: The error is telling you there's an error in your SQL code, not in the Java code which *generates* your SQL code.  Start by looking at the runtime value of `"SELECT * FROM library_students.student WHERE StudentID='"+ borrowedBook.getLenderTo()+"'And Permission=1"+"'And StatusMembership='Active'"` when the error occurs.

Comment: To prevent more errors of this type and SQL injection, I suggest you use prepared statements

Comment: You should learn about prepared statements

Comment: No space in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be happening because of the spacing in the query. Try the following format with `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM "
        + "library_students.student WHERE StudentID= ? "
        + "AND Permission=1 AND StatusMembership='Active'");
preparedStatement.setInt(1, borrowedBook.getLenderTo());
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Also, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099425/when-should-we-use-a-preparedstatement-instead-of-a-statement) some bonus reading on why you should use `PreparedStatement` in this case.

Comment: Darshan I thought that would have been the issue, the missing spaces (hence my upvote), but well... check this [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pmR3g2MYb9hj7Qw5qxcDEZ/0)

Comment: @Cid have you tried copy pasting the above query in the console? I think it might be both spacing and the quotes. However, I suggested `PreparedStatement` solution to get rid of quotes and have a clean query.

Comment: Do you mean Naya's one?

Comment: I totally agree with you concerning the spaces and the prepared statements (too much people here don't care about it) but it looks like MySQL accept such statements `StudentID='10'And Permission=1`

Comment: @Cid Agreed, MySQL does accept such parameters. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The real issue was a typo, as stated Naya in his answer. I voted to close since this is typographical

Answer (score 4):

You're generating the next query :

```
SELECT * FROM library_students.student WHERE StudentID='10'And 
Permission=1'And StatusMembership='Active'
```

Probably the error is because of extra single quotes ' in `Permission=1'And`