# How to improve performance of JDBC query execution?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm running a bot on Discord that receives a lot of requests to the MySQL database, and recently MySQL has started blocking threads, causing major delays in the program.

After dumping the thread,  I've found that the problematic line resides within the PreparedStatement code from JDBC, but I'm really not sure what could be causing this issue.

The code block below is where the error occurs:

```
public List<HashMap<String, Object>> find(String haystack, Object... needles){
    PreparedStatement prep = null;
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        prep = connection.prepareStatement(haystack);
        for(int i = 0; i < needles.length; i++){
            prep.setObject(i+1, needles[i]);
        }
        rs = prep.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            for(int i = 1; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + 1; i++){
                result.put(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), rs.getObject(i));
            }
            results.add(result);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("MySQL > Unable to execute query: " + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        try{
            if(rs!=null)rs.close();
            if(prep!=null)prep.close();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("(find) Error closing: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

with `rs = prep.executeQuery();` being the problematic line of code.

Is there any way to stop MySQL from blocking threads?

Comment: why don't you create a batch in `PreparedStatement` and then execute everything at once?

Comment: I'm honestly unsure on how to go about doing that.

Comment: I see you mentioned that you are getting many request, how you are creating a connection object? Maybe the problem is there. It might be creating lot of connections with MySQL.

Comment: The connection is initiated on startup, then referenced throughout the program.

Comment: So there is only one connection? I would suggest to have a pool of connections. Using connection pooling.

Comment: `The connection is initiated on startup, then referenced throughout the program`. What if one connection is simply not enough, have you  tried a connection pool for this situation ?

Comment: Are there any resources available to get started with connection pooling in JDBC?

Comment: @JakeS. please accept the answer or leave your comments if you are still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using only one connection throughout the application. You should create a pool of connections if you have a large number of request to handle which can be done using following approaches:

1. You can create connection pooling on the application side. You can use [apache connection pool.](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)
2. You can create connection pooling on the server end. [Read this.](https://www.progress.com/tutorials/jdbc/jdbc-jdbc-connection-pooling)
3. Best, use [hibernate](http://hibernate.org/), there you have a property called `hibernate.connection.pool_size`.

If you are using JDBC prepared statement then use [batch processing](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-example-batch-update/) and avoid using `Statement` (which I see you are doing) because of the reason mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548089/which-is-faster-statement-or-preparedstatement).