# What is the best way of inserting data into database in java web application ??

Tags: java, insert

**Approach 1 :**

```
Connection connection=Connector.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps1=connection.prepareStatement("insert into tbl_invtry(part_id,part_name)
                                                  values(?,?,)");
ps1.setString(1,action.getPart_id());
ps1.setString(2,action.getPart_name());
```

**Approach 2** :

```
DAO dao = new DAOImpl(); //DB connection
String query="insert into tbl_entrp_proj(ASPECT_SRC_ID,PRNT_PROJ_ID)values('" + 
                                         project.getASPECT_SRC_ID() + "','" + 
                                         project.getPRNT_PROJ_ID() + "')";
boolean b = dao.insertQuery(query);
```

Please suggest which is the best, and why.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should explain it succinctly. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ashwin and dasblinkenlight stated, SQL injection is the concern.

In Approach 1 you've used parameterized queries to escape any user input to prevent SQL injection, in Approach 2 you've trusted the user to provide values that are directly inserted into your database.

Keep in mind that SQL injected statements may not be a problem on insert, but upon select (or other queries ) could wreck havoc with your data and database.

Not using Approach one is irresponsible at best, and disastrous at worst because of these reasons.

For a secondary reason of why approach 1 is best, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687550/preparedstatements-and-performance) which discusses the performance benefits of prepared statements, and heavily emphasizes the importance of protecting against SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the 1st approach because:

1. It is more efficient - PreparedStatement can be compiled and reused by the database.
2. Security. When using a PreparedStatement, you don't need to worry about encoding and SQL injection.

However, I would consider a 3rd approach - using an ORM framework like Hibernate.