# SQL BLOBs don't end with a null. How do I make it?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, string

So I am using a java SQL api to insert some BLOB data into a table. However, Since the SQL apparently doesn't know that I just want the string to end, it just pads it with zeros. So I have 10 charachters of data followed by a gazillion zeros at the end. How should I solve this problem, and is all hope lost?

```
public void storeInTable(String data) throws SQLException{

    statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO put.data VALUES ('" + data + "', NOW())");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`PreparedStatement#setBlob()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBlob%28int,%20java.sql.Blob%29). [learn more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687550/preparedstatements-and-performance)

It's better explained under *Oracle Tutorial* on [Using Large Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html)

Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/Storeandretrieveanobjectfromatable.htm)

sample code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
preparedStatement.setBlob(index, bais);
```

Answer (score 0):

OP here. in case anyone is having the same problem

REPLACE('" + data + "', CHAR(0), '' )

worked for me. You may want to head the other guy's advice and use prepared statements as well.